# What is the database table for pages?

Tags: database

When I go through the database of a fresh Wordpress 4 install I find, for example:

```
wp_posts
wp_terms
wp_users
```

Yet I didn't find `wp_pages'. Where is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the wp_posts include all post types (post, page, custom post..), and to differentiate between them there is a field called post_type used to specify the name of the current entry whether it's a page, post or a custom post.

Query below will get list of pages

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_type = 'page';
```

Answer (score 0):

I entered to wp_posts and it seems all pages are inside there.

Comment: Welcome to the world of post types!

Comment: The Codex article [WordPress Database Description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) provides an overview of the database tables and fields.  Here's a [great third-party resource which tours the DB in detail](https://deliciousbrains.com/tour-wordpress-database/).